# Finding integral of functions involving e raised to another function.

Tags: calculus

$$\int_0^{\pi/4}(1+e^{\tan\theta})\sec^2\theta\, d\theta$$

I have tried to let $u=\sec^2\theta$ so that $du=\tan\theta \, d\theta$. After doing that I was unable to figure a way to substitute $u$ and $du$ back into my integrand. The integrand I ended up with was $(1+e^{du/d\theta}) u\, d\theta$. This does not seem right to me because I have never learned to deal with the exponent of $e$ if it's even possible. What other approach can I use that involves $u$-substitution?

Comment: Let $u= \tan\theta$. Then $du = \sec^2\theta d\theta$.

Comment: By the way, if $u= \sec^2\theta$, then $du = 2\sec\theta \cdot\sec\theta\tan\theta d\theta = 2\sec^2\theta\tan\theta d\theta$.

Comment: @peterwhy I made a mistake and switched up the integral and derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Try $u = \tan{\theta}$ instead. You'll then get $du = \sec^{2}\theta d\theta$.

As a general point, if you find $d$'s inside a function when trying a substitution, something is terribly wrong.

Comment: I see where I went wrong, I took the integral of u instead of the derivative of u.(Been studying all day and a little stressed) Thanks for the fast response.

Answer (score 0):

put $ tan\theta\ = u $

$ du = sec^2\theta\ d\theta $

suitably your limits change .

so now we rewrite the integral as

$$\int_0^{1/sqrt(2)}(1+e^{u}) du$$.

split the integral as

$$\int_0^{1/sqrt(2)}(1 du ) $$         +   $$\int_0^{1/sqrt(2)} e^u du  $$

evaluate these and substitute back u = $ tan\theta $ and you are done